# How to order/sort a collection into vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to sort/order a collection into Visual Basic, but for the moment with no luck.
The main criterion is to not change the collection into another shape, like List or Dictionary.

My code:

```
    Dim colCols As Collection
    Dim FinalCollection As New Collection

    colCols = New Collection
    colCols.Add(2572, "MyID")
    FinalCollection.Add(colCols)

    colCols = New Collection
    colCols.Add(2576, "MyID")
    FinalCollection.Add(colCols)

    colCols = New Collection
    colCols.Add(2573, "MyID")
    FinalCollection.Add(colCols)
```

I want to order this collection by MyID, and in the final order to be like that: 2572, 2573 and 2576.

Note: FinalCollection is exactly in this shape and is impossible to change that code because is not into my application. So, FinalCollection is received from another application and I want to order the collection into my application.

I try this but with no luck:

```
Dim sortedList = From item In FinalCollection Order By item.Value("MyID")
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you can't read the contents of `FinalCollection` into your own `List`, `Dictionary`, `SortedDictionary`, or `SortedSet`?

Comment: Is this vba or vb.net? It cannot be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. (Even I’m not agree with this approach)

```
Dim newCollection As IOrderedEnumerable(Of Object) = From item In FinalCollection
                                                         Order By CType(item, Collection).Item("MyID")


For Each item As Collection In newCollection
    Console.WriteLine("Order of : " & item.Item("MyID").ToString)
Next
```

Comment: Is perfect, now I have all the items in the proper order. Thanks.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer using collections with dynamic types is not a good approach.
However I’m glad to hear that you have resolved your issue. :)